# My display() function only displays when it enters it the first time. Then it shows a blank window

Tags: opengl

```
void init(void)
{ 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
}
```

void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{ 
    int height = h;
    int width = w;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Complex c(0,0);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    winID = glutCreateWindow("Fractal");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    // Compute the update rate here...
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

I get a square if I put the code in display(), except the glutSwapBuffers() in if condition which checks whether the code has entered display the first time. If I remove the if, I get a white window

Comment: The question is not worded properly. What's your problem?

Comment: `// Compute the update rate here…` no it doesn't. That particular line of code is reached exactly one time in course of running the program. If you have a nonterminating loop there, you'll not reach the GLUT main loop, hence preventing events being processed. Also instead of `display` you should register `glutPostRedisplay` as idle function if you want continous updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an extra `glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f)` in your `display` function, to push everything 5 units back into the scene, otherwise you wont see what you're drawing at the origin.

Btw, the line `glScalef(1.0,1.0,1.0)` doesn't do anything, remove it to avoid unnecessary calculations.

**EDIT**:
There is no "eye" in OpenGL. More specifically, it is always fixed at (0,0,0) looking down at the negative z-axis. You have to move the whole scene with the inverse of the eye transformations. You can either move the scene manually so your eye can see it, or use *gluLookAt*, where you can specify the "eye", but in the background it just transforms the scene so the fixed "eye" can see it.

Further reading: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why does it work fine the first time. Is the default eye location such that it does not cause any problem?